# Problema con claves foraneas en hosting con php

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Hola quisiera que me ayudensi alguien sabe el porque:

cree una base de datos con powerdesigner para Mysql.

Cuando lo cargo en forma local phpmyadmin con xammp funciona todo se crean las claves foraneas.

Pero cuando lo cargo en phpmyadmin de un hosting de hostgator no se crean las claves foraneas.

Que creen que pueda ser?

cree esta de prueba

/*==============================================================*/
/* DBMS name:      MySQL 5.0                                    */
/* Created on:     07/03/2018 14:18:26                          */
/*==============================================================*/

drop table if exists BIBLIOTECA;

drop table if exists LIBROS;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: BIBLIOTECA                                            */
/*==============================================================*/
create table BIBLIOTECA
(
   BIB_CODIGO           int not null,
   BIB_NOMBRE           varchar(30),
   primary key (BIB_CODIGO)
);

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: LIBROS                                                */
/*==============================================================*/
create table LIBROS
(
   LIB_CODIGO           int not null,
   BIB_CODIGO           int ,
   LIB_NOMBRE           varchar(30),
   LIB_PAGINAS          int,
   primary key (LIB_CODIGO),
   FOREIGN KEY (BIB_CODIGO) REFERENCES BIBLIOTECA(BIB_CODIGO)
); 
cuando la cargo en local se crean las FK
pero en el hosting que es hostgator no se crean y no indica ningun error ni nada

Comment: sería ideal para poder auxiliarte que muestres tu script SQL y el resultado que obtienes

Comment: Christian , te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta para evitar sea cerrada**, saludos!

Comment: Quizá en el hosting el engine por defecto es `MyISAM`, el cual no trabaja con FK, en ese caso, tus `CREATE TABLE` deben especificar al final que quieres que las tablas sean creadas en `InnoDB`.

Comment: @Jorgesys saludos gracias

Comment: @AlfredoPaz ya cargue el script para que lo puedan ver

Comment: @A.Cedano si justamente buscando encontre esa solucion pero no funciono porque me genera un error:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB' at line 9

Comment: Al final del `CREATE TABLE` tienes que poner esto: `ENGINE=INNODB`

Comment: Por ej: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (

  task_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  subject VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,

  start_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,

  end_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,

  description VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (task_id)

) ENGINE=InnoDB`

Comment: @A.Cedano Genial muchas gracias ya funciona. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En muchos hosting el `engine` por defecto al crear tablas en MySQL es `MyISAM`, el cual no soporta las llaves foráneas.

Puedes ver todo el [detalle aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html):

```
|Funcionalidad                          |Soportado  |
|---------------------------------------|-----------|
|Soporta llaves foráneas (Foreign key)  |   No      |
```

No obstante, es posible indicar en el `CREATE TABLE` el `engine` que quieres para tus tablas. Cuando no se indica explícitamente, la tabla se crea con el `engine` por defecto que tenga el manejador de base de datos.

Por ejemplo, puedes hacer esto:

```
  -- TABLA BIBLIOTECA
    CREATE TABLE BIBLIOTECA 
    ( 
        BIB_CODIGO int not null, 
        BIB_NOMBRE varchar(30), primary key (BIB_CODIGO) 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;        

  -- TABLA LIBROS

    CREATE TABLE LIBROS 
    ( 
        LIB_CODIGO int not null, 
        BIB_CODIGO int , 
        LIB_NOMBRE varchar(30), 
        LIB_PAGINAS int, 
        primary key (LIB_CODIGO), 
        FOREIGN KEY (BIB_CODIGO) REFERENCES BIBLIOTECA(BIB_CODIGO) 
    )  ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias. Saludos